# Autowiring values using SpEL: referencing beans by type

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-bean

I currently want to automagically set an object's / bean's ID; I got it working so far, but it requires specifying the exact bean name of the counter I'm referencing. Here's how:

```
@Autowired
@Value("#{ counter.next() }")
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

My config has a counter:

```
@Bean
public Counter counter() {
    return new Counter();
}
```

The object that needs an ID set is also defined in the same config as a prototype-scoped bean.

---

Now while this works fine so far, what I would like to do is to autowire the counter by type, not by name. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
@Value("#{ T(packagepath.Counter).next() }")
```

I'm assuming it's only intended for static methods, or at least I got it working by making my counter static - only problem is I don't want that.
Side note: the spring doc is using this format for calling `Math.random()`: `T(java.lang.Math).random()`

---

#### Is it possible to reference beans by type instead of by name when using SpEL in `@Value` annotations (or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

This works...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So52118412Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52118412Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("#{beanFactory.getBean(T(com.example.Counter)).next()}")
    int n;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> System.out.println(n);
    }
}

@Component
class Counter {

    int i;

    public int next() {
        return ++i;
    }

}
```

To explain further; the root object for `#{...}` is a `BeanExpressionContext` which allows access to any bean by name. However, the `BeanExpressionContext` also has a property `beanFactory`, which allows you to reference it, and perform any operation on it (such as getting a bean by its type).